# Obtener palabras de una lista con regex

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Me gustaría saber cómo obtener palabras que contengan el carácter '-' por ejemplo

el texto es:

```
El menu es 

Entrantes:
-Carpaccio
-Tostadas
-Tarta
-Filete
-Risotto
-Lomo
```

Con un regex match me gustaría obtener lo siguiente en un array: `[Carpaccio,Tostadas,Tarta,...]`

Gracias

Comment: Una lista de lo que está entre el guion y un salto de línea?

Comment: si, asi tal cual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si habrá algo que explicar:

- \w* : Buscar caracteres alfanumericos
- - : 1 o más veces
- $:  Hasta el fin de la línea
- /gm: La `m` es para permitir que sea multi línea

```js
let regex = /\w+$/gm
console.log(texto.value.match(regex));
```

```html
<textarea id="texto">-Carpaccio
-Tostadas
-Tarta
-Filete
-Risotto
-Lomo
</textarea>
```